# MVC Bootstrap Data Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables, bootstrap-4

I am new to using this and my first data grid is not showing the sort icons and the formatting is a bit off on where the search bar and pagination should be. Any ideas what I can do to fix this? I have included the below scripts and Styles that are used on my shared layout page. It seems to be grabbing most of the styling, and the search functionality is working. The formatting is just a bit off.

```
@Styles.Render("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css")
@Styles.Render("https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css")
@Scripts.Render("https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js")
```

[image]]

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: no errors, Chrome

Comment: I'm pretty sure on the jQuery Datatables site, it tells you which scripts/css are needed for successful integration.